# Mod-editing another user's post removes the reply arrow from that post

Tags: bug, chat

If you edit another user's message in chat, it removes the reply arrow from that message, so you can no longer reply to it (although you can with the drop down from the left side, but who wants to click *twice*?). If that user then re-edits his message, the reply arrow comes back.

Interestingly, if a mod mod-edits your message, it doesn't *add* a new reply arrow. So this really only affects mods who edit others' messages.

Comment: Star button appears, but also breaks. Flag Button too. Basically, the whole control element over on the right hand side breaks. You can still do all of these things from the pop-up frame that comes from clicking on the left hand side of the message.

Comment: I've noticed this for a while,  but I just assumed it was how the chat system works.