# Editing someone else's chat message disables the reply button

Tags: bug, edits, chat, moderator-tools

When a moderator edits someone else's chat message and submits the edit, the reply button on the message's hover menu disappears.

Some chat conversations revealed this was initially by-design: the system used to be that the reply ping went to the last editor. Having tested this out in chat, that's no longer the case: the reply ping pings the message's author, regardless of edits.

However, it appears the client-side disabling behavior hasn't been changed, and still removes the reply option. This is fixed by a reload, but the button should in theory remain there.

Comment: I disagree with dupe ID. While there's an **answer** highlighting the problem in the linked Q, this **question** is not a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @DeerHunter Then it's most definitely a dupe of [You can no longer quick-reply to a message after you've edited it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169816/you-can-no-longer-quick-reply-to-a-message-after-youve-edited-it) or [Mod-editing another user's post removes the reply arrow from that post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241938/mod-editing-another-users-post-removes-the-reply-arrow-from-that-post)... both of which are duped to the question I linked.